# AWS - Dynamodb streams combining multiple events into a single stream for lambda trigger – unwanted stream aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Disclaimer: I may be misusing terms due to a poor understanding of how streams, shards, etc work.

I have setup a dynamodb table to trigger a lambda function using streams. The pipeline is:

1) Item added to dynamodb

2) Lambda triggered with info from new item added to dynamodb

3) Lambda modifies item in dynamodb

Very importantly, I need each new item to trigger an individual lambda instance. This has been working very well so far. However, sometimes I have noticed that it will combine multiple dynamodb Insert events into a single stream and so it triggers my lambda with info from multiple different inserts if they were made at the same time–which my lambda function is not capable of dealing with. Is there any way around this? To force it to trigger a different lambda instance for each new insert?

Below is an example of a lambda being triggered by an dynamodb stream with multiple events. What I want is the list of records below to never have more than one event.

````
{'Records': [{'awsRegion': 'eu-west-2',
   'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1562924320.0,
    'Keys': {'id': {'S': 'fakedata1'}},
    'NewImage': {'constraints': {'S': 'fakedata1'},
     'id': {'S': 'fakedata'},
     'status': {'S': 'RUNNING'}},
    'SequenceNumber': '212050800000000001290145608',
    'SizeBytes': 310,
    'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'},
   'eventID': '2e0348cfb304f4182cad18d326197031',
   'eventName': 'INSERT',
   'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb',
   'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:1562924320:table/mylambdafunc/stream/2019-05-28T16:42:58.716',
   'eventVersion': '1.1'},
  {'awsRegion': 'eu-west-2',
   'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1562924328.0,
    'Keys': {'id': {'S': 'fakedata2'}},
    'NewImage': {'constraints': {'S': 'fakedata2'},
     'id': {'S': 'fakedata2'},
     'status': {'S': 'RUNNING'}},
    'SequenceNumber': '212050900000000001290146992',
    'SizeBytes': 214,
    'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'},
   'eventID': '944e6d6776f78051f5b3e0e1af0ad207',
   'eventName': 'INSERT',
   'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb',
   'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:501873828238:table/mylambdafunc/stream/2019-05-28T16:42:58.716',
   'eventVersion': '1.1'},
  {'awsRegion': 'eu-west-2',
   'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1562924328.0,
    'Keys': {'id': {'S': 'fakedata3'}},
    'NewImage': {'constraints': {'S': 'fakedata3'},
     'id': {'S': 'fakedata3'},
     'status': {'S': 'RUNNING'}},
    'SequenceNumber': '212051000000000001290147068',
    'SizeBytes': 326,
    'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'},
   'eventID': '9f3d5a16390b6afce6f812d48588269e',
   'eventName': 'INSERT',
   'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb',
   'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:501873828238:table/mylambdafunc/stream/2019-05-28T16:42:58.716',
   'eventVersion': '1.1'}]}```
````

Comment: What's preventing you writing your code to handle multiple streamed events? This is  normal behavior from a streamed interface.

Comment: @jarmod The problem is lambda timeouts. The reports I'm running may not finish within 15minutes if there are multiple of them. I would have to look into asynchronous processing and recursively calling the same lambda function again with the various records, but was hoping there was an easier alternative.

Comment: If multiple records are present then your Lambda could simply send one message per record to SQS and then have SQS trigger a Lambda (maybe the very same Lambda function) for each message on the queue.

Comment: Feels like you want to reduce number of lambda invocations to process  whole stream records. You should be able to specify "Batch size" for your Event Source mapping in lambda. If this doesn't work then you can poll the stream, process records whatever you can the time limit and checkpoint and trigger another lambda by your polling setup.

Comment: I ran into the same issue as well, were you able to understand why multiple events would come through instead of just the one record that got changed?

Comment: @NaguibIhab nope, I had to implement a workaround

Comment: what was the workaround?

Comment: Sorry for slow response... I just made a check in lambda to check if there was a single stream coming in or multiple streams and act accordingly.